# JSF Popup page to Parent (opener) page

Tags: java, jsf

How can I get backingbean content from popup page backingbean to Parent Window.Opener page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to manually fill the `window.opener`'s input fields by JavaScript.

Much easier is to use a fullworthy JSF modal dialog component in combination with a view scoped bean. For this purpose, PrimeFaces has a `<p:dialog>` and RichFaces a `<rich:popupPanel>`. This doesn't require you any line of custom JS code.

Comment: Hey BalusC... Thanks a lot...
Actually, I have to have use opener as there are multiple navigation  happening in  **window.opener** - **a child page**.

I have a question ... Can I pass collection in java script? As I have to pass list - `ArrayList<SomeObject>` to backingbean of parent JSP page. I really tried alot for whole day today for this functioning and still :( :( no luck... 
At the end I have to use session or context (Application) if no any way....

Comment: JavaScript != Java. You need to convert Java to JavaScript. Perhaps you need to step back and learn basic HTML/CSS/JS as well. As said, much easier is to use an existing JSF component so that you're ready with only a few JSF tags.

Comment: Thanks BalusC... It was really critical. I have to tackle it through session at the end. :(